# Load local text file line by line

Tags: jquery, html, load, local

I am use this code for local load a file in my HTML:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "atxtfile.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            jQuery("#showtxt").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This displays the text file but every line in the text file is not displayed as new line in the HTML. So how can i load the txt file and show it how it's displayed in the txt file?

And how can i reload the file every 10 a 20 seconds so i get the new data from the txt file?

Comment: Spit the `data` variable by new line, then loop through it and wrap each line in `<p></p>`. As for loading the text file every 20 seconds, use a timer, note though that you may get some concurrency issues depending on when the file is saved and how many users are accessing at once. It's for this reason that using the filesystem as a data store is not a great idea.

Comment: Gaby have the CSS solution for the new line (simple css) but how can i do the reload? (i am not a very good JS guy) And only one person wil use the HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space:pre` on the `#showtxt` element in html. (*this will maintain the text structure in the file*)

```
#showtxt{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

(*or `pre-wrap` if you want long lines to wrap*)

If you want to wrap each line in `p` you should not use the CSS but instead split the string before appending it to the page and do it line-by-line

```
success : function (data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n'),
                htmlLines = '<p>' + lines.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';

            jQuery("#showtxt").html(htmlLines);
        }
```

---

for the reloading every 20 seconds use a function for the ajax and a `timeOut`

```
function readText(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "atxtfile.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n'),
                htmlLines = '<p>' + lines.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';

            jQuery("#showtxt").html(htmlLines);
            setTimeout( readText, 20000 );
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    readText();
});
```

Comment: This is great thnx! The white-space is working nice but is it possible to wrap the lines in a p or span also?

Comment: @Maanstraat updated answer to include a solution which splits the lines and wraps each in a `p`

Comment: @Maanstraat the code for the line splitting was a partial code (*just the part that should be replaced in your original code. the success method of the ajax call*). I have now included it in the full solution with the timeout. So the last codeblock in my answer should cover all issues.

Comment: You're the greatest! :-)

Comment: I do not have \n in my text file, but its line by line, how can I read?